# How to execute enrich policy while snapshot running in elastic PowerShell?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to execute enrich policy using PowerShell but at the same time snapshot is running, which resulting below error.

`The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.`

Cannot delete indices that are being snapshotted. Try again after snapshot finishes or cancel the currently running snapshot.

But when I am retring getting below error

`{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"es_rejected_execution_exception","reason":"Could not obtain lock because policy execution for`

Is there any way to wait executing enrich policy.

Comment: It's probably because the enrich policy is trying to delete the old enrich index after creating the new one, but the old enrich index is being snapshotted. You just need to wait until your snapshot is done.

Comment: is there any specific parameter to pass, in the enrich api url so that it can wait, i am using powershell and snapshot runs very long.